# Odd behaviour origin to 3d cursor

Tags: 3d-cursor

I'd simply like to set the origin of some meshes to the 3D cursor which is centered using SHIFT + CTRL + ALT + C.

For some reasons that doesn't work anymore with some of objects the character I'm working on. (With the shoes It still works).

The version of Blender I'm using is still 2.69.

[image]

EDIT 1 : Here is the file with the issue (I've installed the last version of Blender in the meantime as well and the problem is still there).

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9BrCn1hOwOWdk44STRyV3l3dzA

Note that at the moment the only solution I've found is to import the model in a new scene with the append function of blender.

Comment: No, nothing yet.

Comment: Try applying scale before positioning origin. Also are there any constraints / modifiers on mesh ? Are objects parented ?

Comment: @Azuk could you provide a .blend file to be able to help you?

Comment: This is most likely caused by any deformation hapenning on your mesh, like rigs, armatures, deformation modifiers, shape keys etc. You mesh is deformed and moving the center creates unexpected behavior. Try temporarily disabling all deformation before proceeding

Comment: In the pivot point Median point from 3D cursor

Comment: @Tak I've just edited the description and put a link to the file with the issue. In the meantime I've fixed it by creating a new scene and then I used the append function by going through File > Append... It's a workaround. That's probably a bug unless someone finds an explaination.

Comment: This is somehow caused by Rigid Body World... If you apply Scale and Visual Transform with Ctrl+A menu and then delete Rigid Body World, the object will be more predictable. However I'm not aware of Rigid Body well enough. I don't think it's a bug though - it's likely that object takes into account presence of physics and changes its location when changed origin point.

Comment: @MrZak Rigid body World ? I'm not sure I follow you. However I tried to apply all transformations with CTRL+ A (scale, location, rotation), but oddly when I do that, the mesh moves, it rotates as well. What I don't get is I haven't used any rig, shape keys, bones that could cause that behaviour if I understand well the comments I've read... It's just a simple mesh. Unless I've missed something.

Comment: The object will obviously rotate and/or shift if you apply rotation and location while Rigid Body physics still affect it. As I wrote apply *Visual Transform* and Scale, then delete Rigid Body World.. Here are [these steps shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGe3E.gif). Once I set origin to geometry it worked well.

Comment: Your comment should be the answer as It is the solution to my problem. Thanks, I now understand what was wrong.

Comment: I've downloaded your file and I copied the mesh you're having trouble with to a brand new blend file and Origin to 3D Cursor is working just fine! In your original file, it's acting really weird and I don't know why...

Comment: Update: Removing Rigid Body physics also seems to solve the problem. I don't know about physics so I can't help you there but it does seem like the problem is related to that!

Comment: It could be some possibilities to cause the problem. I did the job as Mr Zak and also **clear all keyframe** of that object, and the problem sloved. I haven't found what exactly make the issue, but I do need clear keyframes also.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, I have never seen that shortcut used before, However, You can move the origin down to the location you want it in object mode, tab into edit mode, and move your object back up to its original location, this should produce the same result.